# Spring security session time out

Tags: java, spring, session, spring-security

My configuration of session timeout doesn't work. It show me a message that I made when tu user is inactive for 1 minute. But whenever I refresh the page. The session Still persist.

```
   <session-config>
    <session-timeout>
      15
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

Here is the session config of my web.xml and here is the spring security xml

```
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" access-denied-page="/faces/forbidden.xhtml" entry-point-ref="casAuthEntryPoint">
<intercept-url pattern="/faces/parameters.xhtml" access="hasRole('TMS_ADMIN')" />
<intercept-url pattern="/faces/*" access="hasRole('TMS_USER')" />

<session-management invalid-session-url="adfasdf" >
    <concurrency-control error-if-maximum-exceeded="true" max-sessions="1"/>
</session-management> 
</html>
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well after days of looking how to do it. Reading the documetation and everything. I found my answer. In my jsf page i put this code

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="${session.maxInactiveInterval}"/>
```

Then I modify my springsecurity.xml

```
<session-management invalid-session-url="/index.html" />
```